# Is the ANTLR4 PostgreSQL Grammar broken?

Tags: postgresql, antlr4, antlr4buildtasks

I have downloaded Lexer and Parser .g4 files from [github grammars-v4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/sql/postgresql)

In Visual Studio I started a new Class Library project with the packages Antlr4 4.6.6 and Antlr4.Runtime.Standard 4.13.1

When I build the class library I see the following Errors

```
mismatched input 'options {' expecting COLON while matching a lexer rule    PostgresSqlClasses  ...\PostgreSQLLexer.g4  1421

mismatched input '=' expecting COLON while matching a rule  PostgresSqlClasses  ...\PostgreSQLLexer.g4  1422    

mismatched input ';' expecting COLON while matching a rule  PostgresSqlClasses  ...\PostgreSQLLexer.g4  1422

mismatched input 'options {' expecting COLON while matching a lexer rule    PostgresSqlClasses  ...\PostgreSQLLexer.g4  1616
```

and

```
mismatched character '<EOF>' expecting ']'  PostgresSqlClasses  ...\antlr4.codegenerator\4.6.6\build\Antlr4.CodeGenerator.targets   132
```

I can see that the grammar files have been updated very recently.  Am I missing something or could those .g4 files be in error?

-- Bart Kiers' answer below would suggest it is not the Grammar files in error, but something to do with my Visual Studio 2022 or, perhaps, Java setup.

-- Confirmed that there is nothing wrong with the grammars following Bart's generous assistance below.

I am now following Kaby76's suggestion using the Antlr4BuildTasks approach.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="PostgreSQLLexer.g4" />
    <None Remove="PostgreSQLParser.g4" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Antlr4 Include="PostgreSQLLexer.g4">
        <Package>AntlrPostgresClasses</Package>
        <AntOutDir>GeneratedOutput</AntOutDir>
      </Antlr4>
    <Antlr4 Include="PostgreSQLParser.g4">
        <Package>AntlrPostgresClasses</Package>
        <AntOutDir>GeneratedOutput</AntOutDir>
      </Antlr4>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Antlr4.Runtime.Standard" Version="4.13.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Antlr4BuildTasks" Version="12.7.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I can see that some, but not all, .cs units are being generated - now I see the error

> CS0246    The type or namespace name 'PostgreSQLLexerBase' could not be
> found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)   AntlrPostgresClasses    C:\Repos\PostgresParsers\AntlrPostgresClasses\GeneratedOutput\PostgreSQLLexer.cs    35

and

> CS0246    The type or namespace name 'PostgreSQLParserBase' could not be
> found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)   AntlrPostgresClasses    C:\Repos\PostgresParsers\AntlrPostgresClasses\GeneratedOutput\PostgreSQLParser.cs   38

```
the error occurs within the newlygenerated units
```

On kaby76's advice I added the 4 files found [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/3fd48c00f75fd1ab2e51d0100772020d9c71b3b6/sql/postgresql/CSharp) and the class library now builds.

Strangely, it didn't build first time but it seems to be happy now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This time seems as good as any to correct misconceptions in using the [grammars-v4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master) grammars, the Antlr4 tool and runtime for C#.

The [postgresql](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/7f1d17c6d8b0b8e2dc6f2a9efa8320e3e8298e70/sql/postgresql) grammar is not broken. But, you should use a version of Antlr greater than or equal to 4.10. [The postgresql grammar requires version 4.10 or newer, as declared in the desc.xml file](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/7f1d17c6d8b0b8e2dc6f2a9efa8320e3e8298e70/sql/postgresql/desc.xml#L3). The grammar uses the [caseInsensitive option](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/7f1d17c6d8b0b8e2dc6f2a9efa8320e3e8298e70/sql/postgresql/PostgreSQLLexer.g4#L43), which was added in Antlr 4.10. Other grammars use more recent features. And, while this grammar has [a Go language port](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/7f1d17c6d8b0b8e2dc6f2a9efa8320e3e8298e70/sql/postgresql/Go), the grammar doesn't really work with the Go target (likely it is too slow). For these reasons, it is a good idea to peruse [the desc.xml file](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/7f1d17c6d8b0b8e2dc6f2a9efa8320e3e8298e70/sql/postgresql/desc.xml).

You should not use Sam's Antlr4cs fork, not only because it can't really work with this grammar, but because it's pretty old. You can tell if you are using this fork if your .csproj contains any `<PackageReference>` to any of these packages:

- [Antlr4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Antlr4)
- [Antlr4.Runtime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Antlr4.Runtime)
- [Antlr4.CodeGenerator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Antlr4.CodeGenerator)

Development of the Antlr4cs fork stopped years ago. Instead of `<PackageReference Include="Antlr4.Runtime"/>`, use `<PackageReference Include="antlr4.Runtime.Standard" />`.[Antlr4.Runtime.Standard](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Antlr4.Runtime.Standard) is the package build from [the official Antlr4 source runtime](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/tree/dev/runtime/CSharp/src). You really should avoid having a .csproj that contains a reference to [Antlr4.Runtime.Standard](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Antlr4.Runtime.Standard) and any of the old Antlr4cs packages together. Use one or the other, but preferably Antlr4.Runtime.Standard.

You can write a driver, download Java, download the Antlr4 .jar, etc., etc., etc., or you can test using the procedure outlined in [the Wiki](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/wiki#using-trgen-all-targets) using [Trash](https://github.com/kaby76/Domemtech.Trash).

Since you already have dotnet installed, chances are you only need to install a few dotnet tools to generate a C# driver.

```
dotnet tool install -g trgen
dotnet tool install -g trglob
dotnet tool install -g triconv
dotnet tool install -g trparse
dotnet tool install -g trxml
```

Then, you can generate and test a parser in C#.

```
git clone https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4.git
cd grammars-v4/sql/postgresql
trgen -t CSharp
cd Generated-CSharp/
dotnet build Test.csproj
./bin/Debug/net7.0/Test.exe ../examples/aggregates.sql
./bin/Debug/net7.0/Test.exe ../examples/aggregates.sql -tree
```

You can use the command line to build, compile, and run, or you can open the generated Test.csproj file in VSCode or VS2022, and just "F5" to build the parser from scratch, compile, link, and run the parser from the input window.

Even if you want to write the driver from scratch, I would recommend that you use a nuget package to automatically manage the build dependencies for your program. You do not want to get in the habit of downloading the Antlr tool .jar, downloading and installing Java, manually running `java -jar antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar ...`, etc. You should use [Antlr4BuildTasks](https://github.com/kaby76/Antlr4BuildTasks). It is a drop-in replacement for the [Antlr4 Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Antlr4). The package contains all the logic to automatically download a Java runtime environment, generate the parser source code from the Antlr tool, compile and link. You can build directly in VSCode, VS2022, or from the command line Cmd/Cygwin/Powershell/etc using dotnet or msbuild. Antlr4BuildTasks was forked from the [Antlr4cs code](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/tree/bc7fb74f3cf64f656cf2c9c1e05d71386e580a41/runtime/CSharp/Antlr4BuildTasks), and updated. It contains many bug fixes and improvements on the old Antlr4cs package.

There is currently no good extension for VS2022 for Antlr4 grammars. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=antlr&target=VS&category=All%20categories&vsVersion=&sortBy=Relevance . Your best bet is to use VSCode and [Mike's excellent extension for Antlr](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mike-lischke.vscode-antlr4). Or, you could use [Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) with the [Antlr4 extension](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7358-antlr-v4). Normally, I use VS2022 and use [Mads' "Open in VSCode"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.OpeninVisualStudioCode) if I need to have an extension that is Antlr4 aware.

Comment: Fabulous - thanks so much @kaby76

Comment: still no joy.  I have gone with the Antlr4BuildTasks approach but the class library will not  build : The type or namespace name 'PostgreSQLLexerBase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) AntlrPostgresClasses C:\Repos\PostgresParsers\AntlrPostgresClasses\GeneratedOutput\PostgreSQLLexer.cs 35 Active

Comment: I don't know how you are setting up you code and .csproj. But, from the error, you are not including the support code. PostgreSQLLexerBase is contained here: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/3fd48c00f75fd1ab2e51d0100772020d9c71b3b6/sql/postgresql/CSharp/PostgreSQLLexerBase.cs. You need to copy everything in [this directory](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/3fd48c00f75fd1ab2e51d0100772020d9c71b3b6/sql/postgresql/CSharp) to your project. Here is a repo with the grammar with trgen-generated driver:  https://github.com/kaby76/so77625976

Comment: I wish I could double-upvote you.

Comment: Am I wrong - did trgen -t generate those missing files?  I think that is why I removed them.

Comment: No. Trgen just copies the files, which are written by hand, to the same directory as where the .g4's reside. But for CSharp you could leave them in a subdirectory. MSBuild will recursively scan the directory.

Answer (score 1):

Without any code generator/build tooling, I have no issues.

I downloaded the following:

- `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/sql/postgresql/PostgreSQLLexer.g4`
- `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/sql/postgresql/PostgreSQLParser.g4`
- `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/sql/postgresql/CSharp/LexerDispatchingErrorListener.cs`
- `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/sql/postgresql/CSharp/ParserDispatchingErrorListener.cs`
- `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/sql/postgresql/CSharp/PostgreSQLLexerBase.cs`
- `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/sql/postgresql/CSharp/PostgreSQLParserBase.cs`

and put the classes in the namesapce `TestAntlr`. I then did:

```
java -jar antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar -Dlanguage=CSharp -package TestAntlr *.g4
```

Then I ran:

```cs
// <PackageReference Include="Antlr4.Runtime.Standard" Version="4.13.1" />
var lexer = new PostgreSQLLexer(CharStreams.fromString("SELECT something FROM somewhere"));
var parser = new PostgreSQLParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));

Console.WriteLine(parser.root().ToStringTree(recog: parser));
```

without issues.

Comment: ok, thanks - i will follow your example and report back

Comment: it seems my java skills are lacking - I downloaded antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar and dropped it into C:\java\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.312-2.b07.dev.redhat.windows.x86_64\lib then executed the command java -jar antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar -Dlanguage=CSharp -package AntlrPostgresClasses  *.g4 when I execute : Unable to access jarfile antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar

Comment: Add the JAR file in the same folder where you run the `java -jar antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar ...` command. Or do `java -jar C:\java\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.312-2.b07.dev.redhat.windows.x86_64\lib\antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar ...`

Comment: thanks - I did that and it ran with 2 warnings {non-fragment lexer rule AfterEscapeStringConstantWithNewlineMode_NotContinued can match the empty string}

Comment: Yeah, saw that too, the parts that trigger those warnings are intentionally placed in the grammar. You can ignore them: it will not cause parsing issues.

Comment: but I have a PostgreSQLParser.cs to work with now

Comment: I would still like to get it working out of VS but that sees me right for now

Comment: For VS to work, I guess the build tool 4.6.6 needs to be able to cope with the grammar.

Comment: I did see that there was another ANTLR Targets from Sam Harwell which may be the answer